# How to hide progress bar in excel

Tags: excel, progress-bar, vba

I have created a macro in excel which saves data at some remote location; now the problem is if the network connection is slow it shows a progress bar reflecting the remote location with the name of file where the data is being saved, I want to hide that progress bar to keep my remote location unknown for end users.

Comment: Do I understand correctly: you want users to save their files to a "hidden" location? So they have read and write access to this location but may not know where it is?

Comment: Correct ..if the network is fast then it does not show any such bar but it becomes a problem in case of slow network connection.  I am saving data of the excel sheet to some remote excel file.

Comment: This seems to be rather about security and the lack thereof in Excel. Anybody can look into your VBA code and easily see the location anyway. At this point you can try to make it harder with password protection on VBA and saving the location on a protected sheet and so on... All of this is futile and can be easily overcome within less than 10 minutes (without any crack tools from dubious internet sites). So, I'd recommend that you re-think your security strategy. If you still want to go down this route then I'd export data to that location using `Write` or `Print` into a `FreeFile()`.

Comment: as far as i remember `application.ScreenUpdating=False` will hide the saving progress bar, however bear in mind it actually stops any other screen updates

Comment: Thanks Ralph.... for your suggestion, the sheet and VBA code all are password protected; the only problem is "it shows a progress bar when transmitting and saving data to the remote excel file in case of slow network access" that i don't want or want to hide.